# http status 500 null error on servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I am using servlet to delete row on sql. I have set up a textfield that allow to enter number of table and pass the value to deleteHandler.java(servlet) to be checked and deleted. I come across HTTP status 500 with this message

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
addHandler.doPost(addHandler.java:47)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

it seems like addHandler.doPost has encountered a problem (which is in this case, it returns a null)

Here is my addHandler code on line 46 to 47

```
int tableNo = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("tableNo"));
int paxNo = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("paxNo"));
```

the delete.html form is submitted to deleteHandler which later deals with the deletion of the number of table entered in the form. Unlike the add, the delete.html only has 1 input which is tableNo while the add has an extra paxNo. the question is how does the addHandler cause error on the deleteHandler?

Here is the code to my deleteHandler

```
//get parameter
    int tableNo = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("tableNo"));
//connect to DB
            Connection conn = null;
            String db = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/resto";
            String db_driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String user = "root";
            String pass = "";
try {

                Class.forName(db_driver);
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db, user, pass);

                //read
                PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("delete from reserve where table_No = values(?)");                   
                stmt.setInt(1, tableNo);
                stmt.executeUpdate();
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

Here is the code to my delete.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Delete table</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="deleteHandler">
    <label for="studentName">Table No.</label>
    <input type="text" id="tableNo" name="tableNo"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Similar to delete.html, this is add.html extra field

```
<label for="studentID">pax amount:</label>
     <input type="text" id="paxNo" name="paxNo"/>
```

What seems to be the problem here? Please help me solve the problem. Extra explanations are greatly appreciated.

Edit : the link provided says that it occurs because of input file is not a number whereas in my code, there is no input for that particular code in the deleteHandler and even though i entered a number, it would still show the same error. The link provided gives me no explanation of why the error occur even when input value is not needed.

Comment: Perhaps you have the add handler class mapped by mistake to `deleteHandler` in your web.xml.

Comment: I have my servlet set as `<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>deleteHandler</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/deleteHandler</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>`

Comment: Yes, but what servlet class did you map to it?

Comment: Thankyou! Got it working by changing servlet class name.